# Unable to add subdomains with nginx server

Tags: server, configuration, nginx

I have nginx running on my server and I'm trying to set up a sub domain in the server. Once I tried and it worked without any problem. This is the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3) I followed

I have subdomains such as [this](http://nz.proitzen.com/) nz.mydomain.com

Now I'm trying to setup another domain as nickies.mydomain.com

I did exactly what I did initially. But nginx doesn't pick up the site, though the config file shows up inside sites-enabled. You can preview the domain [here](http://nickies.proitzen.com)

This is my config file

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/apps/nickies/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name nickies.proitzen.com;
}
```

Also another peculiar thing I noticed. All other config files have color formatting in vi editor (e.g commented lines are marked in separate color) but even when I copy the same file to create new file the same color format is not getting applied in the file.

`sudo nginx -t` doesn't return any error message at all. Everything looks fine except the domain is not working. Is there any limitation on number of domains in nginx?

What am I missing here? This is driving me nuts for last 6 hours.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the correct way, but after adding a A Record to the subdomain (pointing to my vps server), it started to work.

Comment: Yep, that's what you needed.  It's always two steps.  Configure the server, and configure DNS.

Comment: @codenoire thanks :) That clears most of the problem out then.

Comment: hi, what exactly did you do to solve the issue?